# Is Quantization implied in Maxwell's theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

So as per Maxwell an electric charge oscillating at a certain frequency emits and absorbs radiations only of that frequency. So is quantization somehow implied here.?

And I think Max Plank used the same idea while imagining the oscialltors on the walls of blackbody.

Comment: Resonance is not the same thing as quantization

Comment: @AaronStevens that looks to be the start of an answer

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing quantum about the fact that when you push something with a certain frequency it responds to you with that same frequency. Just try to solve the equations for a free particle in an electric field:
$$ m\ddot{x} = qE_0 \cos \omega t$$
You will get the position is oscillating with the same frequency. Quantization happens when the **amount** of energy absorbed and emitted is quantized.